# PYTHON [td[x+4].a.string for x in range(0,len(td),5)] >> ERROR /////// td[4].a.string >> 'the good string'

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to extract information from an html type file.

> td = beautifulsoup.find_all('td')
>
> td[4].a.string

returns

> 'the good string'

then when I try a recursive operation

> [td[x+4].a.string for x in range(0,len(td),5)]

this returns the following error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

What is happenning?

Thank you, have a nice day,

Vasco

Comment: what is happening is that in that particular tag, there is no 'a' attribute. So it's returning with `None` and you cannot use `.string` with `None`

Comment: Thanks you Chitown88, I am sure you are right.

Comment: But if you were able to read the beginning, you'd understand the question. Let me get you through it: once you've brightly understand the tag had no a attribute, you'll ask: " why in the beginning the same exact tag has an 'a' attribute? and you can use .string with a non None" Thanks Chi, you surely have a piece of it, the gene

Comment: I did read the beginning. The first element you are using `.string` for very well could have an `a` attribute. but you are using it in a list comprehension to create a list of those strings.  but does td[5+4] have an `a` attribute? and does td[10+4] have an `a` attribute? and so on. all of those elements would need to return some value for that list to be generated within that list comprehension. if you were to change the list comprehension to a `for` loop, and use the `try` statement, you could avoid getting the exception when `None` is returned for that tag/element

Comment: Chitown88, thank you for the answer. Yes, this is what was puzzling me, all the elements, I checked one by one using the index number, have an a Element/Tag 'a'. I finally managed to get my answer avoiding the 'a' Tag and going for a '.text' straight. But that was dirty as, for some Elements, it was encompassing a lot of useless information I had to delete manually.

Answer (score 0):

try using a `for` loop with `try`, and you could possibly see where you are returning None, which is where you get the error:

```
for x in range(0,len(td),5):
    try:
        print (td[x+4].a.string)
    except:
        print ('No <td a> attribute for td[%s]' %(x+4))
```

Comment: I'll have a try, and post the html file. For the whole exercise, I was trying to create a list from the outrightHTML of the code/currency/country table at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Comment: I won't have chance tonight, but I'll look at that table you linked tomorrw